# Improving my query efficiency - reducing full table scans?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I was wondering if you could help me out I currently have a working query, but I feel it is not as efficient as it could be.  Ill go on to explain:

I have a car table and a carEvent table.  Car table just stores info such as make, model etc of the car. CarEvent table stores events which happened on the car such as car has been crashed or car has been fixed. If no status of "CRASHED" exists on the carEvent table for a given car  then it has not been crashed.  What my query does is return all cars which have been crashed but not fixed.  The way I have wrote it requires two scans of he carEvent table.

What im wondering is, is there a more efficient way to do this query?

my query is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Car c 
WHERE (select count(ce.id) FROM CarEvent ce
       where car_id = c.id AND ce.carEventType = 'CRASHED') > 0 
  AND (select count(ce.id) FROM CarEvent ce
       where car_id = c.id AND ce.carEventType = 'FIXED') = 0
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, the infamous `count()` in a subquery.  You want to use `exists`, not `count`:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Car c 
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 FROM CarEvent ce where ce.car_id = c.id AND ce.carEventType = 'CRASHED') AND
      NOT EXISTS (select 1 FROM CarEvent ce where ce.car_id = c.id AND ce.carEventType = 'FIXED');
```

For performance, you want an index on `CarEvent(car_id, carEventType)`.  Also, be especially sure to use table aliases in correlated subqueries.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response and sorry for my late reply.  This answer was perfect.  Thanks for the other people who also contributed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *  FROM Car c
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 FROM CarEvent ce
              where car_id = c.id AND ce.carEventType = 'CRASHED')
  AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 FROM CarEvent ce
                  where car_id = c.id AND ce.carEventType = 'FIXED')
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of joins can be reduced from two to one by using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select Car.id
from Car
join CarEvent on Car.id = CarEvent.car_id
group by Car.id
having
    sum(case when carEventType = 'CRASHED' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
    and
    sum(case when carEventType = 'FIXED' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```